# Python - Merging 3 different dictionary and grouping the output

Tags: python

I have created 3 different dictionary in python , however I believe this cannot be merged into 1 dictionary e.g. NewDict due to a same Key in all 3 e.g. Name & Company.

```
NewDict1 =  {'Name': 'John,Davies', 'Company': 'Google'}
NewDict2 =  {'Name': 'Boris,Barry', 'Company': 'Microsoft'}
NewDict3 =  {'Name': 'Humphrey,Smith', 'Company': 'Microsoft'}
```

I would like to group above in such a way that my output is as below :

Google : John Davies Microsoft : Boris Barry, Humphrey Smith

Any help will be really appreciated .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicts = [NewDict1, NewDict2, NewDict3]

out = defaultdict(list)

for d in dicts:
    out[d['Company']].append(d['Name'])
    
dict(out)
```

output: `{'Google': ['John,Davies'], 'Microsoft': ['Boris,Barry', 'Humphrey,Smith']}`

###### as printed string

```
for k,v in out.items():
    print(f'{k}: {", ".join(v)}')
```

output:

```
Google: John,Davies
Microsoft: Boris,Barry, Humphrey,Smith
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, is there any way i could output the result in plain text format i.e. remove brackets , e.g. Google : John Davies Microsoft : Boris Barry, Humphrey Smith

Comment: @Ady sure, simply loop over the dictionary items (see update for an example)

Answer (score 1):

```
NewDict1 =  {'Name': 'John,Davies', 'Company': 'Google'}
NewDict2 =  {'Name': 'Boris,Barry', 'Company': 'Microsoft'}
NewDict3 =  {'Name': 'Humphrey,Smith', 'Company': 'Microsoft'}
d = {}
l = [NewDict1, NewDict2, NewDict3]
for each in l:
    if each['Company'] not in d.keys():
            d[each['Company']] = []
    if each['Name'] not in d[each['Company']]:
            d[each['Company']].append(each['Name'])
```

Outputs:

```
d
{'Google': ['John,Davies'], 'Microsoft': ['Boris,Barry', 'Humphrey,Smith']}
```

For Plain text

```
output = ''
for k,v in d.items():
    v = [x.replace(',',' ') for x in v]
    output+=f" {k}:{','.join(v)}"
output = output.strip()
```

Print(output) and you get:

```
'Google:John Davies Microsoft:Boris Barry,Humphrey Smith'
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate for the swift response. Is there any way i can get the output in plain text format e.g. Google : John Davies Microsoft : Boris Barry, Humphrey Smith

Comment: Sure, please check edit, also removed the commas in output.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a different structure for your source dictionary ?
like instead of `{'name': 'jack', 'company': 'google'}`, go for

```
dict1 = {'Google': ['Jack']}
dict2 = {'Microsoft': ['Susan']}
dict3= {'Google': ['Amit']}
#then you can combine all three dict into one: 
def combine_dict(dict_1, dict_2):
  for key in dict_1:
    val = dict_1[key]
    if key in dict_2:
      dict_2[key].extend(val)
    else:
      dict_2[key] = val
  return dict_2
new_dict = combine_dict(dict1,dict2)
new_dict = combine_dict(new_dict, dict3)

this should do it
```

Comment: This replaces Jack with Amit

Comment: Sorry my bad, let me correct that

Comment: Nice, gave you an up !